# Unable to play certain videos with QMediaPlayer

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmediaplayer

I have a Qt 5.3 application that plays videos which works fine for some videos.  Unfortunately when given some .mov files, I either get a `QMediaPlayer::FormatError` or I can hear audio but no video.

I am assuming this is due to missing codecs, is there a way to add support so that I can play the videos?

EDIT: This is on OS X

Answer (score 1):

QMediaPlayer can play any format that the platform's media service supports. You should install the right codecs for a video type to be played successfully. Try to install GStreamer codecs on Linux. If you are on Windows install KLite Codecs.

QtMultimedia's implemention is platform dependent (uses direct show on windows, gstream on linux etc). May be it is good to consider using libraries like [QtAV](http://wang-bin.github.io/qtav.org/) or [libVLC](https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC/).

They work for most platforms and no additional codecs and plugins are required to install.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention in my initial question that it is running on OS X.  I will have a look at those libraries tonight.

Comment: Quicktime plays the videos fine, but my application still has the same problems.  Long term I will probably go with one of those libraries, but I would like to get the videos working short term. I have installed a bunch of codecs under /Library/QuickTime, but it doesn't seem to have helped.